# Network Error and "FirebaseError: internal" Occur when Calling Cloud Run Function from iOS 15.7.6 Safari

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm encountering an issue where I receive a network error and a "FirebaseError: internal" message when attempting to call a Cloud Run function from Safari on iOS 15.7.6. About every 10th attempt fails for me. In my Sentry logs it shows a lot of iPhone devices with different iOS versions and Chrome or Safari. I have checked my network connectivity and confirmed that it is stable.

I am using Firebase as my backend, and the Cloud Run function is responsible for handling specific requests. The Cloud Run function itself runs smoothly.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this problem? I have already researched the Firebase documentation and other relevant resources, but I haven't found a solution yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can try to call and reload https://app.heyinvite.com/event/KSxhLruF8Wc7XSo9MFu2
multiple times on a iPhone with Safari browser.

Here you can see the error logs (after them is the successful request):

[image: The network error]

[image: The firebase logs]

The successful log:

[image]